# jquery not working with update panel

Tags: jquery, updatepanel

I have the following markup;

```
 <fieldset style="width:40%;">
    <legend> Site User Role Management</legend>
    <asp:Label ID="lblSiteUserDDl" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlSiteUsers"
         Text="Manage the roles in which a user is registered by selecting the user from the dropdown list below."></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSiteUsers" runat="server" CssClass="dropdowns" AutoPostBack="True" />
    <br /><br />
    <fieldset id="rolemanagement" style="width:80%;" runat="server" >
        <legend></legend>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentRole" runat="server"  CssClass="literaltext"></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSiteUserRole" runat="server" CssClass="literaltext"></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserRoles" CssClass="dropdowns" runat="server"/><br />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSiteUsers" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

and the following script at the bottom of the page

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%= ddlSiteUsers.ClientID%> ').change(function () {
            $(this).css({ 'color': 'black', 'font-size': '1.1em', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
            var selecteditem = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
            $('#<%= lblCurrentRole.ClientID%>').html("You selected the user: <span style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>" + selecteditem + "</span>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that the first label DOES change properly but is removed when the page is returned by the update panel. I have tried all the various solutions I've found via google but none seem to work. For now the fieldset with the two labels and the dropdown is always visible, ultimately once I get the labels to display properly that fieldset will be hidden until the upper dropdown selection changes.

Comment: have you looked at jquery's on function? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `lblCurrentRole` outside the update panel or populate it's value server side.  Since the problem is that it is being replaced, you need to either keep it out of the container that is being replaced or set the value server side so that the returned HTML will have it set correctly.

Using a set of spans, server-side, to update the value of the label.

```
 lblCurrentRole.Controls.Clear();

 var textSpan = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
 textSpan.InnerText = "You selected the user: ";
 lblCurrentRole.Controls.Add(textSpan);

 var userSpan = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
 userSpan.InnerText = ddlSiteUsers.SelectedValue;
 userSpan.Attributes.Add("class","selected-user");
 lblCurrentRole.Controls.Add(userSpan);
```

Comment: I can certainly set the text in the code behind, I actually started with that. If I do that then how do I add the span tag then to have the username bolded?

Comment: You could add a `HtmlGenericControl` set to the span, probably add two spans one containing the first part of the text, the other containing the highlighted part.  I'd use a class on the span that corresponds to the style you want rather than setting the style directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this method . This may help you.

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (evt, args) {
  //Write your jquery function here
});